# why I have to use `drop` manually on unused rust variable to pass lifetime checker? Why doesn't `query` dropped before `url.as_str()`

Tags: rust, lifetime

Why I have to run `drop(query)` manually to make the code compile? In my opinion, the `drop(query)` should be called implicitly in that place and has a very short lifetime.
**The demo code**:

```
// Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "lifetime1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
url = "*"

// src/main.rs
use url::Url;

struct MockUrl {
    name: String,
}

struct MockQuery<'a> {
    test: &'a mut MockUrl,
}

impl MockUrl {
    fn take_mut(&mut self) -> MockQuery<'_> {
        MockQuery { test: self }
    }

    fn get_name_immut(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }
}

fn main() {
    // case A: why drop is needed?
    let mut url = format!("{}/v2/private/position/list", "https://www.baidu.com").parse::<Url>().unwrap();
    let mut query = url.query_pairs_mut();
    drop(query); // position A
    println!("{}", url.as_str());

    // case B: works as expect.
    let mut t1 = MockUrl { name: "name".to_string() };
    let mut t2 = t1.take_mut();
    println!("{}", t1.get_name_immut());
}
```

Comment: The compiler explains why in the error message; what do you not understand about the compiler's explanation?

Comment: @Herohtar In the opinion, the `query` should be implicit dropped as soon as possible before `url.as_str()` is called. When `url.as_str()` is called, there should be only one immutable reference, just like case B.

Comment: That's not how [destructors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html) work in Rust, and the compiler shows that `query` will not be dropped until the end of `main()`. Is your actual question why it isn't dropped before then?

Comment: @Herohtar I am going to read this article, thanks very much!

Comment: @Herohtar Exactly! Why it isn't `query` dropped before `url.as_str()`?

Comment: You should read the linked page if you want to understand it fully, but variables aren't dropped until they go out of scope. In this case, the scope for `query` is the `main()` function, since it's a [local variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#scopes-of-local-variables).

Comment: @Herohtar What about `t2` variable in Case b? Why this variable is dropped before `t1.get_name_immut()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242212/discussion-between-color-and-herohtar).

Comment: `t2` isn't dropped until the end of `main()` either. I'm not sure what exactly is causing the difference, but I think it might be the complexity -- in your `MockUrl` case, it's fairly straightforward for the compiler to see that nothing else happens to the `String` so it allows the immutable borrow "early", but in the case of the `Serializer` class returned from `query_pairs_mut()`, the compiler is unable to make the same determination so it has to be more strict.

Answer (score 4):

Without the `drop()` call, this message from the compiler hints us at the problem:

```
mutable borrow might be used here, when `query` is dropped and runs the
destructor for type `Serializer<'_, UrlQuery<'_>>`
```

The answer is that the type returned by `url.query_pairs_mut()` implements `Drop`<sup>1</sup> to customize what happens when the value is destroyed, and values aren't automatically dropped until the end of the block containing the declaration of the variable in which that value lives.  Since `Drop::drop()` takes a (mutable) reference to the value being dropped, this necessarily extends the length of the borrow on `url` until the end of `main()`.

Since your type doesn't implement `Drop`, the line that declares and initializes `t2` is also the last time the value in `t2` is used in the function, so `t2`'s borrow of `t1` can end there.  If you implement `Drop` on your `MockQuery` type then the borrow of `t1` by `t2` *can't* end early and so you will see the same error from the compiler as you saw with `query`:

```
impl<'a> Drop for MockQuery<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) { }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=764a9508155b44753ff46f4c68f4f8ec))

Dropping `query` explicitly destroys the value contained in it, which necessarily causes the custom `Drop::drop()` implementation to be invoked at that point, and therefore ends `query`'s borrow of `url` early.

---

<sup>1</sup> It doesn't implement `Drop` directly, but the struct contains a member of a type that does implement `Drop` and this struct member holds the borrow on `url`.

Comment: Thanks very much, much, much, much, much, much...!!! Great help for me.

Comment: That's what I was missing. I looked at `Serializer` to see if it implemented `Drop`, but didn't think to look at the types contained in that struct itself.